# Help with linq query, problem with skip and take when joining on multiple queries

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I want to throw out on my home screen a bunch of notifications, however I am using paging to ensure I dont concat 2,3 or 4+ queries in memory which could have thousands of results. I am having a bit of trouble writing this query, any guidance would be appreciated...

Domain Model: I have a bunch of reports, you can create/close report, create tasks and comment on the task which is all related to the report.

**My query needs to send out:**

1. All new reports created (based on date created)
2. All reports closed (based on closed date)
3. All New tasks created on this report (Task manager helps to keep track of things happening)
4. All latest comments on a task

My code so far:

```
[NonAction]
private IList<NotifcationDTO> GetNotifications(LoggedonuserDTO loggedonuser, int skip, int take)
{

  var allreports = _repo.All<Report>();

  var alltasks = _repo.All<ReportTask>().Join(allreports ,
                       x => x.ReportID, y => y.ReportID, (_task, _report) =>
                       new
                       {
                          _report,
                          _task
                        })
                       .Where(x => x._task.CompanyID == loggedonuser.CompanyID || x._task.AssignedToCompanyID == loggedonuser.CompanyID);

  var _companies = _repo.All<Company>();
  var _users = _repo.All<User>();

  var _activities = alltasks.OrderByDescending(o => o._task.DateCreated)
                    .Select(x => new NotifcationDTO
                    {
                      Title = x._report.SubjectPropertyAddress1,
                      MessageID = x._report.ReportID,
                      NotificationType = NotificationType.NewTask.ToString(),
                      Comment = x._task.Title,
                      Importance = Importance.Medium.ToString(),
                      Timestamp = x._task.DateCreated,
                      UserFriendlyName = _users.Where(y => y.UserID == x._task.UserID).FirstOrDefault().Login,
                      EntityFriendlyName = _companies.Where(y => y.CompanyID == x._task.CompanyID).FirstOrDefault().Identifier
                    });

   return _activities.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

**//Update- query to concat onto...**

```
var comments = _repo.All<InstructionTaskComment>();

var _taskcomments = alltasks
                            .Join(comments, x => x._task.TaskID, y => y.TaskID, (_task, _comment) => new
                            {
                                _task,
                                _comment
                            })
                            .OrderByDescending(o => o._comment.Timestamp)
            .Select(x => new NotifcationDTO
            {
                Title = x._task._report.SubjectPropertyAddress1,
                MessageID = x._task._report.ReportID,
                NotificationType = NotificationType.Comment.ToString(),
                Comment = x._comment.Comment,
                Importance = Importance.Low.ToString(),
                Timestamp = x._comment.Timestamp,
                UserFriendlyName = _users.Where(y => y.UserID == x._comment.UserID).FirstOrDefault().Login,
                EntityFriendlyName = _companies.Where(y => y.CompanyID == x._comment.CompanyID).FirstOrDefault().Identifier
            });
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the code you have?

Comment: What are you asking for help with, writing the query? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I have added the second query above, basically I want to concat both queries keeping in mind paging, I dont want to do an in memory concat...

Comment: Or, is there a better way to get the 4 different types of notifications I have listed above? Rather than doing it all in one method and sending it out to my view in one go? Make sense?

Comment: I just realised I can do a concat and the query is not in memory and my paging is kept intact :p -             return _newtasks
                .Concat(_taskcomments)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp)
                .ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all the collections you are working with are `IQuerable` they will be traslated into SQL and no "in memory concatenation" will be done. You can use a tool like to [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see the corresponding SQL generated.